# what is the squence of jquery files

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have these jquery files included but some plugins work and some are not when i change squence then some plugins work but other give error. Please tell me best squence of these files. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/urdutextbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_10_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sitefunction.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't ever include 2 different versions of jQuery!

Comment: Wow, you have included jquery library 3 times!

Comment: i download different plugins which use different jquery library if i remove some one the plugin not work

Comment: Before you include any library you should understand what it does. You have three copies of jQuery in at least two versions, and two copies of jQuery-ui, one minimised and the other as source. Rationalise what you have and include only what you need.

Comment: If your plugins use different jquery versions you may use `jquery migrate`

Comment: yes dear this work jquery migrate

Answer (score 0):

This would work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sitefunction.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/urdutextbox.js"></script>
```

Also note that you do not need to include normal and minified versions (*.min.js). And since jquery-ui.js depends on jquery core code, it could be kept down to jquery core.

Also please note that you may not require two or more versions of a jquery core thing as it might not make any sense. Instead if you really wish to have some recently added functionality, please make your own custom file by going to jquery custom build at [this link](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

Answer (score 0):

Just because a version of jQuery requires a certain version doesn't mean it won't work with a later version.

I would try to remove:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

I would also completely remove this since there's no way for a plugin to work after you remove `jQuery` as a global.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery_1_10_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Also, you're free to remove the `type="text/javascript"` from your `script` tags, no issue with it but it's not needed.

I'd put your site functions after all the other scripts are include as well, and I'd put `jquery.cookie.js` before the `ui` stuff, just as preference.

So, I'd end up with:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="js/urdutextbox.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sitefunction.js"></script>
```